# How to get viewport content CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is there a way to find out which data model nodes are currently visible in the viewport?

I was trying to mark all container nodes with id, and get viewport dom nodes then find and match ids, but this solution is too slow on big texts.